# Taking a screenshot of aframe scene

Tags: aframe

I want to be able to grab a screenshot of the scene. I didn't find any documentation but I do remember once upon a time seeing someone discuss this on slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='https://rawgit.com/AdaRoseEdwards/f6b96e4ea44c0201bc72879da62e633a/raw/9074d13fdbc540a0b4b578009c2fac79711359ba/equirectangular.js';document.body.appendChild(script);})();
```

Comment: I will probably put this into a function and post back here, but in the url bar this works perfectly. Thanks!